# Power analysis for contingency table

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power, contingency-tables

Following a cardiac surgery a patient will be classified into one of four categories: Nothing, Mild, Moderate, Severe. There is a new test which, when performed after the surgery, claims to be able to predict which category the patient will fall into. This information can then be used to implement an intervention that will hopefully reduce the number of patients being classified as Mild, Moderate, and Severe.

So the object of the analysis is to determine if the information from the test does result in fewer patients being classified as Mild, Moderate, or Severe.

There are two groups, the control group (103 patients) who received the usual standard of care and the study group (94 patients) who received the test and the intervention if they were predicted to fall into the Mild, Moderate, or Severe category.

The results were:

```
Control: 73 (Nothing), 22 (Mild), 8 (Moderate), 0 (Severe)
Study: 72 (Nothing), 18 (Mild), 1 (Moderate), 3 (Severe)
```

Because the counts were so low in the Moderate and Severe categories I decided to combine them:

```
Control: 73 (Nothing), 22 (Mild), 8 (Moderate/Severe)
Study: 72 (Nothing), 18 (Mild), 4 (Moderate/Severe)
```

Using the SciPy Chi-square test of independence of variables in a contingency table as follows

```
freq_table = [[73, 22, 8], [72, 18, 4]]
sps.chi2_contingency(observed=freq_table, correction=True)
```

I get that the Chi-squre test statistic is `1.33` with a p-value of `0.513`, so that I fail to reject the null hypothesis that the test and intervention resulted in a statistically significant decrease in the number of patients who get categorized as Mild, Moderate, or Severe.

Given how small the numbers are in the Moderate and Severe categories, does it make sense to get some more Study group patients? That is, does the question of performing a power analysis make sense? If the test is truly predictive and performing the intervention when the test indicates to do so does actually have an effect, how many more (study group) patients would I need to collect to find a statistically significant difference?

If performing a power analysis makes sense, how would I do so in this case - I am not sure how to measure 'effect size' given that I have a contingency table.